# Create ID variable according to levels of a second variable

Tags: r

using R I would like to add an ID variable to a data frame, but I would like it to start over at each level of a second variable in the data.frame (terrible sentence, hopefully an example helps).

So, I know how to create an ID variable that extends the length of the data.frame using mutate

```
dat <- mutate(dat, id=rownames(dat))
Var1    ID
1        1
1        2
1        3
1        4
1        5
1        6
2        7
2        8
2        9
2       10
2       11
```

But what I would really like is the ID variable to start over once the Var1 hits 2 (then 3, then 4, etc). I figure you can use some type of apply function, or possibly dplyr, but I'm not sure with one. Below is what I am trying to do.

```
Var1 ID
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
1    5
1    6
1    7
2    1
2    2
2    3
2    4
2    5
2    6
2    7
2    8
2    9
3    1
3    2
3    3
3    4
3    5
3    6
3    7
3    8
3    9
```

Comment: Maybe you should tag with the package you're using...`plyr` or `dplyr` for this `mutate` thing? It might also help if you show what `dat` looks like initially (before it's overwritten).

Comment: `with(dat, ave(Var1, Var1, FUN = seq))`?

Comment: Bingo! Thanks, David!